# Specifying CloudSQL Postgres instance name in Springboot configuration

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-proxy

I'm working on connecting a CloudSQL Postgres instance to a Springboot application. The connection currently is on JDBC and is specified in the application.properties

```
app.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
app.datasource.username=dbuser
app.datasource.password=dbpass
app.datasource.pool-size=30

@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource")
public HikariDataSource dataSource()
{
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build(); 
}
```

With CloudSQL, I've changed the url, username and password. I'm told I also need to specify the Postgres instance name, without which the connection seems to be failing.

I tried adding in app.datasource.instance="instance-name", but that doesn't give me any resolution.

Any advice here?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Are you using spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql? If so, your configuration looks incorrect. See https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.1.0.RC2/multi/multi__spring_jdbc.html#_spring_boot_starter_for_google_cloud_sql for details.